# Bot framework DialogContext.Continue does not work

Tags: c#, botframework

I have implement a bot using Microsoft Bot builder SDK v-4 (pre-release). To manage the conversation flow I have used two simple dialogs-

**GreetingDialog - DialogBegin:** To greet the user first time

```
public Task DialogBegin(DialogContext dc, IDictionary<string, object> dialogArgs = null)
{
    var state = dc.Context.GetConversationState<EchoState>();
    string greetMessage = string.Format("Hi, I am {0}.", _botName);
    dc.Context.SendActivity(greetMessage);
    IList<CardAction> suggestedActions = new List<CardAction>
    {
        //some card action suggestions
    };
    var activity = MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(suggestedActions, text: "Please select the area of conversation.");
    dc.Context.SendActivity(activity);
    dc.End();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**ConversationDialog - DialogBegin:** To continue the subsequent conversation after the user has been greeted

```
public Task DialogBegin(DialogContext dc, IDictionary<string, object> dialogArgs = null)
{
    string activity = "test";
    dc.Context.SendActivity(activity);
    dc.Continue();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I am calling the `GreetingDialog` in the `ConversationUpdate` event and the `ConversationDialog` in the subsequent message received event, within the `OnTurn` method in my Bot class.

**OnTurn event in my Bot class:**

```
public async Task OnTurn(ITurnContext context)
{
    var state = context.GetConversationState<EchoState>();
    var dialogCtx = _dialogs.CreateContext(context, state);
    if (context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        //Greet user first time
        if (context.Activity.MembersAdded[0].Id == "default-user")
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!context.Responded)
        {
            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["greetingArgs"] = context.Activity.Text
            };
            await dialogCtx.Begin("greetingDialog", args);
        }
    }
    else if (context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await dialogCtx.Continue(); //this line is supposed to execute Begin the active dialog again??
        //if (!context.Responded)
        if(dialogCtx.ActiveDialog == null || !dialogCtx.Context.Responded)
        {
            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["conversationArgs"] = context.Activity.Text
            };
            await dialogCtx.Begin("conversationDialog", args);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I get redirected to `ConversationDialog` but it only happens through `await dialogCtx.Begin("conversationDialog", args);`. Isn't it supposed to redirect to `DialogBegin` of the Active dialog when I do `await dialogCtx.Continue();`? I can see the Active dialog is 'conversationDialog' and the debugger steps over through `await dialogCtx.Continue();`. Any help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. We can implement the `IDialogContinue` interface for our Dialog class like this-

```
public class QnADialog : IDialog, IDialogContinue
{
    public Task DialogBegin(DialogContext dc, IDictionary<string, object> dialogArgs = null)
    {
        string activity = "test";
        dc.Context.SendActivity(activity);
        //dc.Continue();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task DialogContinue(DialogContext dc)
    {
        dc.Context.SendActivity("dc continue");
        dc.Context.Responded = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then we can use the `DialogContinue` method to handle the `DialogContext.Continue()` from the calling code.

Comment: Hi Souvik! I'm used to sending people FROM Github TO Stack Overflow to get their questions answered, but because this is v4 shenanigans, this is something the v4 developers should be aware of. If you could post this on the [BotBuilder v4 C# SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet), we can see if this is intentional, or something that needs to be brought to the dev's attention.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I am not sure if I can raise this as an "issue" on Github channel. This is something which I failed to understand and there seems no problem with the SDK/bot emulator.